# sleepy VERSUS half-asleep: the usage

Tags: meaning

Is it true that SLEEPY is used before someone goes to bed and HALF-ASLEEP is used not long after the person woke up?

Comment: How bizarre! Someone has closevoted this question on the grounds that you should have just looked it up in the dictionary! I'm sure there are at least *some* ELL users with better credentials than me for ruling on the meanings of words, but I'm a native Anglophone with a degree in English Language & Literature, plus quite a bit of my income over a lifetime was for programming a number of different "word games" for British and European publishing houses. And I don't see how you could look up the answer to this question *anywhere* (apart from my chart, which apparently finds little favour! :)

Answer (score 16):

> [sleepy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleepy):
>
> tired and wanting to sleep

> [half-asleep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20asleep):
>
> not completely awake : very tired

Being *sleepy* is more about how you feel, while being *half-asleep* is more about how lucid and conscious you are. A person that's sleepy feels tired but usually can still do things, while someone who's half-asleep is either nearly dozing off, or hasn't yet woken up fully.

Either can be used both before and after falling asleep - if you make yourself stay up too long while you're *sleepy*, you'll probably end up *half-asleep* on the chair once the fatigue catches up with you. On the other hand, if you didn't sleep well you'll probably be *sleepy* after you wake up, and if something suddenly wakes you up you might be *half-asleep* for a while.

Comment: I believe your attempts to draw a *semantic* distinction are spurious. It's just that *idiomatically,* at least some speakers are more likely to use the (far less common overall) form ***half-asleep*** of someone becoming more awake, as opposed to becoming more drowsy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I'm sitting in a lecture and dozing off on a chair or daydreaming, I certainly wouldn't find it unidiomatic being called *half-asleep*, even if I'm not fresh out of bed. And I don't think your charts support your thesis either - all it says to me is that it's rather uncommon to *still feel/be sleepy* after a night of sleep, but common to behave as if you're *still half-asleep*.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but presumably it makes sense to others, or they wouldn't be upvoting it. Are you saying that me choosing to compare ***still** [sleep / half-asleep* isn't likely to distinguish between "**not yet** fully awake" (*after* sleeping) and "**no longer** fully awake" (drowsy/nodding off *before* retiring)? If so, can you suggest any other adjustment I can make to the search terms? Or is it just that people don't believe there's a tendency to use "half-asleep" more freely of people still in the process of waking up rather than "in anticipation" of going to sleep?

Comment: Btw - my chart doesn't remotely suggest that "it's rather uncommon to still feel/be sleepy after a night of sleep". In fact, it specifically shows that ***still sleepy*** is actually slightly *more* common than ***still half-asleep***. The reason for showing the chart is that the two words are *about equally common* after ***still***, despite the fact that *in general*, ***half-asleep*** is very uncommon compared to ***sleepy***.

Comment: I refer you to T.S.Elliot: "...and when you think he's half asleep, he's always wide awake." So the half-asleep...wide-awake is how somebody is or at least is acting, rather than how he actually feels: a sentry might legitimately be tired and sleepy but had better not be seen to be half-asleep.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your argument (as I read it) is that there's no semantic distinction and it's just more idiomatic to say "half-asleep" after you wake up and "sleepy" before you go to bed. My argument is that there *is* a semantic distinction and "still sleepy" is more common than "still half-asleep" because the former combination's meaning represents a rare situation (not feeling rested after you've slept), while the latter's meaning represents a common one (behaving as if you're not fully conscious after you've slept).

Answer (score 3):

It's actually quite easy to prove that OP's suspicion is perfectly correct. First note [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sleepy%2Chalf-asleep&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that overall, ***half-asleep*** is *very uncommon* relative to ***sleepy***...

[image]

...then consider the implications of [this chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=still%20sleepy%2Cstill%20half-asleep&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that after ***still***, ***half-asleep*** is almost as common as ***sleepy***. Obviously almost all of these will be referring to *not long after a person has woke up* - it doesn't normally make much sense to say someone is ***still sleepy*** if they're about to retire.

[image]

I can't offer a convincing *explanation* for this "usage split" - it's not inherently implicit in either of the alternative expressions, and you obviously won't be *wrong* if you say you're ***still sleepy*** some time after waking up. But undeniably the two terms are used somewhat differently.

Comment: Don't forget that the first chart includes some more metaphorical uses of "sleepy", while "half-asleep" doesn't have those.  For example, "_I live in a sleepy backwater_."  A fairer comparison might be "feeling {sleepy,half-asleep}".

Comment: I did think about that, but I seriously doubt there would be enough of those "false positive" matches to affect the message of the first chart. I can't get NGrams' arithmetic functions to work these days, but even if I could *halve* the values for ***sleepy*** (to compensate for 50% of all instances being false positives), the chart would still convey the same message.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's chart #1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feeling+sleepy%2Cfeeling+half-asleep&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) comparing ***feeling** sleepy* and ***feeling** half-asleep*. All it does is make the latter *absolutely* "flatline" - which anything makes my case stronger!

Comment: I might **be** sleepy, or I might **feel** sleepy, or I might **be** half-asleep (or half asleep), but I would never **feel** half-asleep. In my experience "half-asleep" is usually an observation about somebody else.

Comment: @Peter: That's another distinction that means nothing to me. I have no idea how anyone can differentiate *I **am** happy / angry / sad* from *I **feel** happy / angry / sad*. In such contexts, being and feeling mean the same thing to me (ditto ***sleepy / half-asleep***). But I must admit it would be a bit odd to say ***I am ignored*** in *any* context, whereas ***I feel ignored*** is a fairly normal thing to say.

Comment: I find “I feel half-asleep” slightly awkward, too, as well as things like “I feel dead on my feet”. I think the relative dispreference for ‘feeling half-asleep’ is that it is still derived from _asleep_: a state like _asleep_ or _unconscious_ isn’t really something you can _feel_, only be (Ngramming _felt asleep_ vs _was asleep_ shows the latter to be nearly 500 times more common): the very state nullifies your ability to feel (in the cognitive sense), so we _can’t know what it feels like_ to be asleep or unconscious.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That's an excellent point (linking the [dis]preference to oxymoronic ***feeling asleep***, not simply noting that there [is? might be?] a slight aversion to feeling half-asleep). But if I think about it too much, I end up suspecting that I only ***feel upset*** if I'm appealing to my *interlocutor's* empathic qualities. Whereas if I ***am annoyed*** I probably only care about getting radiating my anger (so I'm not interested in garnering sympathy or empathy).